# Vertical layout with CSS without using breaking elements?

Tags: html, css, layout, positioning, vertical-alignment

Is it possible to implement **vertical layout** with **CSS only**, and not with HTML elements?

I have a list of divs inside one div. By default the next element is right to the last, when there's no place on right, it is placed below.

I'd like to achieve the same with CSS style settings. Is it possible?

By CSS-only I mean, we have div and its children, and **do not** add anything special such as:

- line-breaking elements ( `<br/>, <div style="clear:both;"/>` )
- UL tags
- tables (yes, still used, f.g. JSF almost exclusively based on them)

So:

```
<div id="menu">
  <a href="something1">Page 1</a>
  <a href="something2">Page 2</a>
  <a href="something3">Page 3</a>
</div>
```

And CSS implementing vertical layout:

```
#menu { ??? }
#menu a { ??? }
```

Is there a ??? that I could use to achieve what I want?

Comment: so, you want you anchor tags side by side? or on top each other

Comment: one below other, as if there was a <br/> after each anchor

Comment: i have added my answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Display anchor tags as block elements.

```
#menu a {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: It's so simple, I can't believe I couldn't google it searching for vertical positioning using CSS only...

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/7Y9jS/

```
#menu {
    width: 300px;
}

#menu a {
    display: block;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #000;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}


<div id="menu">
  <a href="something1">Page 1</a>
  <a href="something2">Page 2</a>
  <a href="something3">Page 3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

set display block to a

```
#menu a {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use float left

```
#menu a {
    float:left;
}
```

and then add the class group to your #menu

```
.group:before,
.group:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
} 
.group:after {
    clear: both;
}
.group {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}
```